# I can't use Eval inside LinkButton?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I'm inside a `Repeater`. And this is my code for a `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="AggiungiSocial" 
    CssClass="<%# ((Eval("UniqueID").ToString() != SocialEngine.paginaCrushsite.ToString()) ? "dashboard-checkaccess" : "dashboard-crushsite")%>" 
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UniqueID") %>' 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="cmdAggregaSocial_Click">
    Link
</asp:LinkButton>
```

but seems I cannot use Eval inside `CssClass`? It says `The server tag is not well formed.`

Comment: you may try call `DataBind` method for `LinkButton`

Comment: Can you give to me an example Grundy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything is easier than it seemed

> The words Server and Text need a space between them in the tag. Actually, most of the tag needs spacing added between the elements. So try this tag instead, note I've added some spaces between elements within the tag.
>   see more [ASP.NET Gridview the server tag is not well formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233950/asp-net-gridview-the-server-tag-is-not-well-formed)

try change your code like this

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="AggiungiSocial" 
    CssClass='<%# ((Eval("UniqueID").ToString() != SocialEngine.paginaCrushsite.ToString()) ? "dashboard-checkaccess" : "dashboard-crushsite") %>' 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UniqueID") %>' 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="cmdAggregaSocial_Click">
    Link
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the differences with my code? :O Seems that I get the same error...

Comment: in your code `<%#Eval("UniqueID` and `crushsite")%>'` i.e. without any space

Comment: with space and single quotes? or double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using the CssClass expression between single quotes `'` should work:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="AggiungiSocial" 
    CssClass='<%# ((Eval("UniqueID").ToString() != SocialEngine.paginaCrushsite.ToString()) ? "dashboard-checkaccess" : "dashboard-crushsite") %>' 
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UniqueID") %>' 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="cmdAggregaSocial_Click">
    Link
</asp:LinkButton>
```

For better readability, you could use a code behind function that returns the CssClass.

```
CssClass='<%# GetCssClass(Eval("UniqueID").ToString())%>'
```

If for some weird reason nothing worked, implement the repeater `ItemDataBound` event and set the LinkButton CssClass there.

Comment: @markzzz: Try Evaling only the UniqueID inside the CssClass Property. Does it also print the code?

Comment: @markzzz I guess putting the CssClass attribute value calculation inside single quotes, just as written above should work

Comment: I've tested this using a different expression within a repeater. It worked on .NET 4.0 and 3.5.